# R expression function with less than or equal to sign

Tags: r

this is literally driving me crazy. I'm have this line of code that runs in R fine:

```
expression("" <= a)
```

This outputs less than or equal to 'a'.

I have two questions, how do I get ride of the space between the less than or equal to symbol and the constant 'a'? And the second question is, how do I program it so that 'a' is set to the value that is stored in variable 'a'?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to remove the spaces? R doesn't care about them (although for readability, it helps if they are present).

Comment: What does "how do I program it so that 'a' is set to the value that is stored in variable 'a'?" mean? Do you want to do `a = "a"`? Or `a=a`?

Comment: The output of your `expression` line is the expression object. If typed in at the command line it prints "`expression("" <= a)`" which is R's idea of how to print expressions. Expressions are language objects, and spaces are placed according to R's rules. Whatever you are really trying to do here, messing with the output format of `expression` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you actually using plotmath?

Comment: And you might be interested in `help("bquote")`.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, @Roland beat me to it in the comment section. Here's proof that `bquote` should work for your case.

```
> a <- 1
> eval(bquote("" <= a))
[1] TRUE
> eval(expression("" <= a))
[1] TRUE
```